# Bitwise and unsigned int operations in PHP

Tags: php, c++, int, unsigned

I'm trying to convert my C++ code to PHP and I'm stuck, my source codes uses unsigned integers (32bit) and many bitwise operations like rotations, xor, shifting, I'm trying my best to make it work, I'm cutting integers to 32bit

$i = $i & 0xFFFFFFFF;

but still I'm having a lot of troubles (my guess it has something to do with multiplication/division) this time.

Are there any libraries for PHP that handles operations on 32bit unsigned integers, any other ideas are also welcome :) Thank you :)

Comment: What specific problem are you having?

Comment: You can make an unsigned integer (in string form) from a signed negative integer this way: *$unsigned = sprintf('%u', -5);*; most of what you need should be in the GMP library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look of how Java programmers handler unsigned int's

http://www.javamex.com/java_equivalents/unsigned.shtml

I guess that's the only way of doing it...

Answer (score 0):

All integers in PHP are signed.

There are however answers for bitwise operations here:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Comment: also, for more info on PHP integers: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems few years ago. It turned out that problem was in operative system which was 32-bit. Switching to 64-bit OS solved problems for me.